# Master detail tables inside a transaction in EntitFramework core and atomicity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

If I have a master and detail tables, how do I create both table records in EntityFramework core, where DetailTable.MasterTableId = MasterTable.Id inside a single transaction, without violating atomicity principle?

I understand that I have to call SaveChanges on MasterTable in order to retrieve MasterTable.Id, but SaveChanges is a transaction commit so atomicity would be broken...

Oh I forgot to mention, MasterTableId is auto increment and the databse is sql server

Comment: Entity decorations should take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have proper navigation property, `EF` will take care of it.

Suppose we have two tables and `C#` classes `MasterTable` and a `DetailTable`.

```
public class MasterTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public DetailTable DetailTable { get; set; }
}

public class DetailTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MasterId { get; set; }

    public MasterTable MasterTable { get; set; }
}
```

And we need to configure `Master-Detail` relationship. I prefer to do with `Fluent API`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MasterTable>()
    .HasOne(a => a.DetailTable)
    .WithOne(b => b.MasterTable)
    .HasForeignKey<DetailTable>(b => b.MasterId);
```

Now we want to store a `Master` with `Details`. We will just add detail with master as generally and EF will take care of the rest.

```
      using (var context = new ProjectContext())
        {
            var master = new MasterTable()
            {
                OtherProperty = "Hello",
                DetailTable = new DetailTable()
                {
                }
            };

            context.MasterTables.Add(master);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```